# How to read CheckBox out of a text file WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Well i have figured out how to save a checkbox value into a text file but now i need to now how to read it an load the settings for de application.

```
private void Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName)))
                {
                    TBSOMS.Text = read.ReadLine();
                    TBWVB.Text = read.ReadLine();
                    TBWNB.Text = read.ReadLine();
                    TBASPMM1.Text = read.ReadLine();
                    TBASPMM2.Text = read.ReadLine();
                    TBDUM.Text = read.ReadLine();
                    TBADPR.Text = read.ReadLine();
                    TBAR.Text = read.ReadLine();
                    // Not working part
                    CBXY1.IsChecked = read.ReadLine();

                    read.Close();
                    read.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

everything works properly except the checkbox value and i cant figure out how to fix it

Comment: You read in tex from a filet. `CCBXY1.IsChecked` is a bool property. Convert the textual representation in your file of your checkboxstatus into a bool - you can try `bool.Convert(read.ReadLine())` f.e. It is unclear what you are exactly doing, because you do not show your textfile, how you save it.

Comment: when using `using(....) { ... }` context you do not need to Close/Dispose the Stream.

Comment: Sorry for that, at the moment i'm saving it as false or true. Guess that i have to change that]

Comment: as what should i save it then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `read.ReadLine()` returns a string, but `CBXY1.IsChecked` has to be a boolean. What you need to do here is to parse the line you've read and convert it into a boolean.

If the line in your text file contains ONLY either `true` or `false`, you can use `TryParse` to get at the correct boolean value, like this:

```
bool shouldBeChecked;
if(bool.TryParse(read.ReadLine(), out shouldBeChecked))
{
    CBXY1.IsChecked = shouldBeChecked;
}
```

This code reads the line from your file and tries to parse it into the corresponding boolean value. If, and only if, the line could be parsed, i.e. it contained either the word "true" or "false", the result is assigned to the boolean variable `shouldBeChecked` and the code inside the `if` statement is executed.

Inside the `if` statement you now only have to set the state of your checkbox to the result of the parse operation, `shouldBeChecked`.

Be aware that if the text if your file is NOT either `true` or `false`, e.g. the line has a text of "true, foo, bar" or such, the parse operation will return `false` and the code inside the `if`statement is never executed.